# Added new key-value to object in an array fetched from an API and trying to toggle the key value, but its undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, redux, next.js

So basically, I'm fetching products from an API and I added a new key value `isAdded` to the object inside the products array, I used `foreach` loop to add that key and its succesfully added, now when I hit `Add to cart` button I'm adding the product item to my `<Cart />` which is also working fine but the only thing I wanna do is when that specific product to added to the Cart I wanna change the text and style of the button, which means I wanna toggle the `isAdded` value. But the `isAdded` seems undefined when I click the button, rest data is going fine but not my key.

BookProduct.js

```
import BookItems from "./BookItems";
import classes from "./book-item.module.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function BookProducts({ booksData }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        booksData.forEach((element) => {
            element.isAdded = false;
        });
    }, []);

    console.log(booksData); //isAdded key perfectly added in the object

    return (
        <div className="container">         
                {booksData.map((el) => {
                    return (
                        <BookItems
                            id={el.isbn13}
                            key={el.isbn13}
                            imageUrl={el.image}
                            price={Number(el.price.slice(1))}
                            title={el.title}
                            subtitle={el.subtitle}
                            link={el.link}
                            isAdded={el.isAdded}
                        />
                    );
                })}     
        </div>
    );
}
```

BookItems.js

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import classes from "./book-item.module.css";
import { cartStoreAction } from "../../store/cart-items";

export default function BookItems(props) {
    const { id, title, price, imageUrl, isAdded } = props;
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const addToCartHandler = () => {
        dispatch(
            cartStoreAction.addProduct({
                id,
                title,
                price,
                imageUrl,
                isAdded
            })
        );
        console.log(isAdded); //isAdded is undefined
    };

    return (
        <div className={classes.product__item}>
            <Link href={`/products/${id}`} className={classes.image_box}>
                <Image src={imageUrl} alt={title} className={classes.image} fill />
            </Link>
            <div className={classes.desc_box}>
                <Link href={`/products/${id}`}>
                    <h3>{title}</h3>
                </Link>
                <div className={classes.bottom}>
                    <p>${price}</p>
                    <button onClick={addToCartHandler}>
                        {isAdded ? 'Added' : 'Add to cart'}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

cart-items.js

```
const cartItemSlice = createSlice({
    name: "cart",
    initialState: {
        items: [],
        totalQuantity: 0,
        totalAmount: 0,
    },
    reducers: {
        addProduct(state, action) {
            const newCartItems = action.payload; //items from dispatch object
            const existingItem = state.items.find((el) => el.id === newCartItems.id);                   
            state.totalQuantity++;
            if (!existingItem) {
                state.items.push({
                    id: newCartItems.id,
                    quantity: 1,
                    title: newCartItems.title,
                    price: newCartItems.price,
                    image: newCartItems.imageUrl,
                    totalPrice: newCartItems.price,     
                    isAdded: !newCartItems.isAdded,
                });
                !newCartItems.isAdded;
            } else {
                existingItem.quantity++;
                existingItem.totalPrice = existingItem.totalPrice + newCartItems.price;
            }
            state.totalAmount = state.items.reduce(
                (acc, index) => acc + Number(index.price) * Number(index.quantity),
                0
            );
        },      
    },
});
```

Comment: What is `booksData` and why are you mutating it in the `BookProducts` component?

Comment: I'm receiving data as a props with this `<BookProducts booksData={props.fetchedData.books} />` on another page by fetching the API.

Comment: Right, I can see that. Don't mutate props. I was asking where that prop value was declared/where it's coming from. Can you [edit] your post to include a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: Please check it here - https://github.com/mohitdevelops/book-store-app/blob/main/pages/products/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are mutating the wrong object. Don't mutate passed props. I'd suggest skipping setting any `isAdded` property in the `addProduct` reducer function and selecting the state in the `BookItems` component to know if an item has been added to the cart already by the item id.

cartItemSlice

```
const cartItemSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: {
    items: [],
    totalQuantity: 0,
    totalAmount: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    addProduct(state, action) {
      const { payload } = action; // items from dispatch object
      const existingItem = state.items.find((el) => el.id === payload.id);
                
      if (!existingItem) {
        state.items.push({
          quantity: 1,
          ...payload,
          totalPrice: payload.price,
        });
      } else {
        existingItem.quantity++;
        existingItem.totalPrice += newCartItems.price;
        isAddedToCart();
      }

      state.totalQuantity++;
      state.totalAmount = state.items.reduce(
        (acc, index) => acc + Number(index.price) * Number(index.quantity),
        0
      );
    },
    removeProduct(state, action) {
      const removingItemId = action.payload;
      const alreadyAddedItem = state.items.find(
        (item) => item.id === removingItemId
      );
      
      if (alreadyAddedItem.quantity === 1) {
        state.items = state.items.filter((item) => item.id !== removingItemId);
      } else {
        alreadyAddedItem.quantity--;
        alreadyAddedItem.totalPrice -= alreadyAddedItem.price;
      }

      state.totalQuantity--;
      state.totalAmount = state.items.reduce(
        (acc, index) => acc + Number(index.price) * Number(index.quantity),
        0
      );
    },
  },
});
```

BookProducts

```
export default function BookProducts({ booksData }) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {booksData.map((el) => (
        <BookItems
          id={el.isbn13}
          key={el.isbn13}
          image={el.image}
          price={Number(el.price.slice(1))}
          title={el.title}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

BookItems

Select the cart items from the store and check if the current `BookItems` `id` prop is a match to an element in the cart items array.

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
...

export default function BookItems({ id, title, price, image }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const cartItems = useSelector(state => state.cart.items);

  const isAdded = cartItems.some(item => item.id === id); // <-- compute here

  const addToCartHandler = () => {
    dispatch(cartStoreAction.addProduct({
      id,
      title,
      price,
      image,
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.product__item}>
      <Link href={`/products/${id}`} className={classes.image_box}>
        <Image src={image} alt={title} className={classes.image} fill />
      </Link>
      <div className={classes.desc_box}>
        <Link href={`/products/${id}`}>
          <h3>{title}</h3>
        </Link>
        <div className={classes.bottom}>
          <p>${price}</p>
          <button onClick={addToCartHandler}>
            {isAdded ? 'Added' : 'Add to cart'}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It worked, thanks alot, now I just need to remove the item when user hit `Add to cart` again, I'll try that first by my own :)

Comment: No sorry, I just checked a few examples on other ecommerce sites, when item is added to cart then the button says "Go to Cart", so I'll probably redirect the button to the Cart page one it's added....

Comment: @Mohit Aye, ok, good luck!

Comment: It's working perfectly, please check the demo yourself here - https://book-store-app-beta.vercel.app/products

And thanks for help, really appreciated :)